# How get list Docker private docker organization images with docker api v2

Tags: docker, docker-api

i am tried this not working am able list my public repository images but origination images

```
curl -L -s 'https://hub.docker.com/v2/namespaces/devops/repositories/core7/tags?page_size=1024'
```

Comment: curl --insecure https://<registryHostnameOrIP>:5000/v2/namespaces/devops/repositories/core7/tags?page_size=1024'

Comment: https://<registryHostnameOrIP>:5000 it's not working my images are stored hub.docker.com in private registry